# Facebook Canvas App Login for new Users

Tags: facebook, canvas, authentication, oauth

i have created a facebook app and it works well for new users if they start the app with the direct server link (https://www.mydomain.com/app/index.php) and use the login button.

But if they try to use the app within facebook (https://apps.facebook.com/myapp) as a canvas app(for the first time) then they see the "landing" page of my app and the log in button. But if they click on it, an errormessage appears, that the  content of the iframe couldn't be displayed.  If they start the app in a new tab, then the login process works. (see the error below, sorry it's german, maybe you are familiar with this type of error message?)

[image]

It would be desirable if the new user could use the login link in the canvas app.

How can this be achieved? My index.php looks like this: (i am using the facebook SDK)

```
<?php

  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {


      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```